# Objects to strings, unique keys in PHP

Tags: php, serialization, object, hash, unique-key

I was reading around about the Observer pattern, and found a dated [article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/5). Having read through, I noticed an interesting mention in this paragraph:

> The key methods to look at here are attach(), detach(), and notify(). attach() and detach() handle adding and removing observers. **We use a little trick here. Objects quoted in string context resolve to a unique identifier (even if __toString() is defined). You can use this fact to build keys for an associative array.** The notify() method cycles through all attached observers, calling update() on each. The UploadManager class calls notify() whenever it has something important to report on upload and on error, in this case.

Which references this example:

```
function attach(UploadObserver $obs) {
    $this->observers["$obs"] = $obs;
}
```

Now as mentioned, this article is dated. Casting objects to strings of course no longer works in this manner (*I run 5.3.6 on my dev box, and push it for all client projects*) but I'd like to achieve similar functionality. I can only think of (*something like*) this:

```
function attach(Observer $observer){
    $this->_observers[md5(serialize($observer))] = $observer;
}

function detach(Observer $observer){
    unset($this->_observers[md5(serialize($observer))]);
}
```

I'm curious, are there any other efficient ways to achieve this; creating a unique key from the object itself.

**Caveat:** I don't want to get into defined keys, I use those often enough with other repositories and such, implementing `__set($key, $value)`, etc.

*Note:* I understand MD5 isn't ideal.

---

**Update:** Just found [spl_object_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php), and I assume this is likely my best choice, however feel free to share your thoughts.

Comment: you have just found or mario have just told you it? :P

Comment: `spl_object_hash` is conceptually broken (returns same hashes for different objects), but you normally do not run into a problem by that when in use.

Comment: @yes123: Found it and was editing. Saved edits, and answers appeared.

Comment: @hakre: it returns same hashes or not?

Comment: Interesting note: According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php#76220 (*given internals haven't changed*) it hashes the internal handle. When an identical object is created immediately after the first has been destroyed, it can produce identical hashes.

Comment: @TomcatExodus: That's the case I was referring to. But that should not be an issue in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that does not work that way any longer. You might want to use some other function instead: [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php)

```
function attach(Observer $observer){
    $this->_observers[spl_object_hash($observer)] = $observer;
}

function detach(Observer $observer){
    unset($this->_observers[spl_object_hash($observer)]);
}
```

The serialization based approach has a design problem btw: I stops working when objects are identical by value or in other words if objects return the same serialized value, e.g. NULL. This is fully controllable by the objects themselves when they implement the  [`Serializable` interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php).

Comment: Thanks **hakre**; Found `spl_object_hash` and was editing as you answered :) Also, yes I'm aware of the Spl interfaces; The mention of the Observer pattern was more of a vessel to my actual question, regarding the object IDs. Thanks for the mention of the serialization issue, hadn't occurred to me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [SPL object hash function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php)?

Comment: Thanks **Robin**; Just found it :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use [SplObjectStorage](http://php.net/manual/class.splobjectstorage.php) directly.

Like:

```
function __construct(...){
    $this->_observers = new SplObjectStorage;
}

function attach(Observer $observer) {
    $this->_observers[$observer] = $observer;
}

function detach(Observer $observer){
    unset($this->_observers[$observer]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks **Yoshi**; Awesome. I'll use this going forward.